# How to get correct values in foreach loop php using continue;

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble trough trying to get the correct values, but it give me some pain to get it done.

Below my code that made a loop trough items and find if the value meet the requirement and var_dump the result but is not correct, also i write below result the output i need.

```
    $requeriment = 250;
    $items = array(
        array(
            'id' => 12,
            'price' => 199, // 2%
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 13,
            'price' => 199, // 2%
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 14,
            'price' => 199, // 2%
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 15,
            'price' => 399, // 1%
            'quantity' => 1
        )
    );

    $flag = false;
    $sumItems = 0;

    foreach($items as $item){
        $totalItem = $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];

        if($totalItem >= $requeriment){
            if(!$flag){
                $flag = true;
                $itemIds[] = array(
                    '1% Disc' => $item['id']
                );
            }else if($flag){
                $itemIds[] = array(
                    '2% Disc' => $item['id']
                );
            }
            continue;
        }

        //If no product with value required lets sum until we get that amount
        $sumItems += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
        if($sumItems >= $requeriment){
            $itemIds[] = array(
                '1% Disc' => $item['id']
            );
            continue;
        }
        $itemIds[] = array(
            '2% Disc' => $item['id']
        );



    }//THE END

    var_dump($itemIds);

    //the result is: 
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["2% Disc"]=>
        int(12)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["1% Disc"]=>
        int(13)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["1% Disc"]=>
        int(14)
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["1% Disc"]=>
        int(15)
      }
    }

    // but what i need is:

    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["2% Disc"]=>
        int(12)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["2% Disc"]=>
        int(13)
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["2% Disc"]=>
        int(14)
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["1% Disc"]=>
        int(15)
      }
    }
```

Comment: The result is expected if you trace the code. As `$sumItems` is increased (one way switch), unless the item itself is above the requirement, you're always going to get "1%"

Comment: At the end you will see the result that the code give me and the result i need, my question is how can i get that result. Thx

Comment: @MetalMichael i see that the issue is on $sumItems, i made this $sumItems for case where there are no items that meet the value of 250, i i change the price for id 15 on 199 it will sum id 12 and 13 and will break.

Comment: Sounds like you need a second loop then, after all of the items have passed?

Comment: The idea is just to get the Ids that need to be applied 1%, so in this way i will made a query that ask for WHERE IN and WHERE NOT IN.

Comment: @MetalMichael, i answered the question and i think is the solution, don't know exactly if flag is needed in the second loop. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I think i made it to work, don't know if flag is needed at the second loop, but it return me what i need:

As @MetalMichael mentioned, maybe i need a second loop, he was right!.

```
$requeriment = 250;
    $items = array(
        array(
            'id' => 12,
            'price' => 199, // 2%
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 13,
            'price' => 199, // 2%
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 14,
            'price' => 199, // 2%
            'quantity' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 15,
            'price' => 199, // 1%
            'quantity' => 1
        )
    );

    $flag = false;
    $sumItems = 0;
    $itemIds = array();

    //Get if value is bigger than required.
    foreach($items as $item){
        $totalItem = $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
        if($totalItem >= $requeriment){
            if(!$flag){
                $flag = true;
                $itemIds[] = array(
                    '1% Disc' => $item['id']
                );
            }
        }
        continue;
    }

    //If first loop get no result lets sum items and get the ids to apply the first discount
    if(!count($itemIds) > 0){
        foreach($items as $item){
            $sumItems += $item['price'] * $item['quantity'];
            $itemIds[] = array(
                '1% Disc' => $item['id']
            );
            if($sumItems >= $requeriment){
                if(!$flag){
                    $flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($itemIds);
```